# How to remove the black line in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, captcha, python-tesseract

[image]

I have the project that I have to read image and get the text from it by pytesseract library. But the problem I have is that all images in my dataset have a black line in the middle. A line is random (the image I put above is one of the examples) and pytesseract can't get the text from image exactly because of that black line. Can you help me to delete the line and show the exactly text from image? I use Python, opencv. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Increase or decrease the `alpha` and `beta` value to get required output.
If you have any doubt refer [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r"img_path")

alpha = 8.0
beta = 15

new = alpha * img + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("removed",new)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Your way is not really optimal. I see the line is still in the image after process, it just fades but not completely gone

Comment: Understand, I'll check and let you know brother